# get variable from function to another javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to pass the value of variable from one function to another

```
function changeParent(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').on('click',function() {
            var x = $(this).attr('id');
            var y = $(this).attr('name');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId',
                data: {'childId' : y},
                success: function(msg) {
                    document.getElementById('names').value = x;
                    msg = x ;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The second function that calls `msg` from the first function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#saveId').on('click',function() {
        alert(msg);        
    });
});
```

I tried

```
alert(window.msg);
```

but it didn't get the last value in `msg`. How I can pass it?

Comment: `$('#saveId').on('click',function() {alert(document.getElementById('names').value);        
 });`

Comment: msg is scoped to the first function, define it globally first. Right at the top just do var x;

Comment: @RickCalder How i can make it global .. i tried window.msg but its not work

Comment: @Adelin i tried alert(document.getElementById('names').value); its not work :/

Comment: Check all 3 answers lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a variable outside of the two functions' scope. There is a `msg` in the success calback function, so when you were calling `msg = x` it actually assigned x to that reference.

```
var message;

function changeParent(){
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a').on('click',function() {
            var x = $(this).attr('id');
            var y = $(this).attr('name');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://test.local/Family.php?action=getId',
                data: {'childId' : y},
                success: function(msg) {
                    document.getElementById('names').value = x;
                    message = x ;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#saveId').on('click',function() {
        alert(message);        
    });
});
```

This way the variable `message` is available for both functions.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

msg is scoped to the first document ready function and is not available to the second function.

```
<button id="btn1">
Button 1
</button>

<button id="btn2">
Button 2
</button>
```

Notice how msg1 is only defined inside the first document ready function, but msg2 is defined globally (not inside a function). Button 1 won't work, Button 2 will, check the fiddle at the end.

```
var msg2
$(document).ready(function(){
  var msg1 = "Hello World"
  msg2 = "Goodbye World"

})

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#btn1").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
        alert(msg1)
  })
  $("#btn2").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
        alert(msg2)
  })
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnj4yLeg/3/

Answer (score 1):

Problem is msg . Your msg in success callback is only local variable also strange is :

```
success: function(msg) {
     document.getElementById('names').value = x;
     msg = x ;
  }
```

// No sense ! msg is arg for callback func

Make global variable :

```
var Message  = '';
```

Intro success :

```
Message = msg;
```